# How to remove a redirect in .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I need to build a website for someone, but it is currently redirecting to an appointment booking software. I checked the .htaccess file and there is some sort of redirect code, not sure how to remove it. I tried replacing the entire .htaccess file with a blank one, and every page on the site said "Page not found". Any suggestions? This is what is currently in the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteOptions inherit

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^suitezen\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.suitezen\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.massagebook\.com\/Bowling_Green\~Massage\~IBTsuitezenmedicalspa$1" [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.massagebook\.com\/Bowling_Green\~Massage\~IBTsuitezenmedicalspa$1" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: _"I tried replacing the entire .htaccess file with a blank one which did not work"_ - Please be more specific than just "did not work". Didn't work how? What actually happened? We don't know your setup at all so it's hard to know exactly what you need to change and where and if changing here is enough.

Comment: Sorry I'll edit my post. I was unable to go access .../wp-admin/ or .../wp-login.php. Everything on the site was saying page not found.

Comment: You still need [the default htaccess](https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/) for Wordpress. You might need to add/change things depending on your setup.

Answer (score 1):

Any line with a `RewriteRule` and the `[R]` flag (in your case written as `[R=302` for a temporary redirect and `[R=301` for a permanent redirect) is a rewrite rule that tells apache to redirect to the given url. The `RewriteCond` lines before the rule modify when the `RewriteRule` after it is executed. In your case you have two redirect rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^suitezen\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.suitezen\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.massagebook\.com\/Bowling_Green\~Massage\~IBTsuitezenmedicalspa$1" [R=302,L]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.massagebook\.com\/Bowling_Green\~Massage\~IBTsuitezenmedicalspa$1" [R=301,L]
```

Delete those and delete the cache of your browser to see Wordpress again. I see that there are some conditions related to cpanel that are not usually part of a Wordpress installation (see the official wordpress site for [an example of the default .htaccess](https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/#basic-wp)). If for some reason the redirects get re-added to your .htaccess, dive into cpanel to see if there is a configuration option there.